# duplicate user account (Nima)

Tags: support, status-completed

The 'Nima' account appears to be duplicated, identical nickname & email addresses but different reputations and openid's.

https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/636/nima
https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/728/nima

Answer (score 3):

This user is **unregistered** so there's not a lot of point in merging, but I did it anyway.

Comment: oh, I didn't notice that. Thanks for the merge. For future reference: should we continue to notify SO Team of duplicate yet unregistered users?

Answer (score 0):

ahh, solution to account dupes appears to "email team@stackoverflow.com with the urls to the two account pages (if known) and the email used and they will merge them." -- [Newly created user account does not count my old posts, even if e-mail matches](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32610/newly-created-user-account-does-not-count-my-old-posts-even-if-e-mail-matches).

Doing so now...